# Can I initiate loading of frame B from frame A?

Tags: html, frames

On my web page I plan to have a "header" containing links to different parts of my site. The same "header" will be present on every page. My header also contain an image.

I started to implement this idea and start to think about frames. I though that my be I should put my header in a frame and the main content will be displayed in another frame. I though that in this way I can avoid reloading of the header. It is always present and only content of the second frame is reloaded (as result of clicking links in the header). Can it be done in this way. Or, in other words, can I initiate reloading of frame B by clicking links in frame A (without reloading of frame A)?

Comment: I would advise you to drop the thought of using frames for websites. Reason is that every frame is a "seperate document" and first of all, some search engines dont even index your content in frames. Secondly, if the search result points to frame instead of your frameset, then the visitor will see that frames content instead of your sitestructure. 

Use modern techniques instead for speed up, if its to get rid of retyping the same content in many pages, consider using a serverside-script language. CGI, JAVA, ASP, PHP ... or something similar which includes and renders HTML on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure, use the target attribute:

```
<a href="whatever.html" target="another-frame-name">
```

But **please** consider not using frames, as usually it creates horrible user experience.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. That's what A's target attribute is for.

Say that you have two frames, top one is named header, main one is called content.

Then, in your header, add target="content" to your links. This will tell browser to load whatever href you specified in links inside of a named frame.

One note, though. You would want to create site without frames these days.